# Error installing Ionic2 on OSX: Error: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: macos, ionic2

I am trying to install Ionic 2 beta on OSX.

```
npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.31
```

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avoid this error is by changing `npm`'s default directory. You can see more options [here.](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

need to start the cmd with `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.31
```

Comment: I think it's not recommended to use sudo in this case... it may cause bigger problems on the long run even it may work in the short term...